# keytool en windows no funciona para obtener hash para Facebook

Tags: android, react-native, openssl

Estoy trabajando con la SDK de Facebook para android sin embargo hay un apartado que me pide generar un hash de autenticación utilizando keytool, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta el la documentación que sigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad debes definir el path de [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) en lugar de `"PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl"`, para esto debes instalarlo previamente, puedes descargarlo desde este [enlace propio para windows](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads).

Cuando lo tengas instalado puedes definirlo en tu comando, como ejemplo yo lo tengo instalado en `C:\Data\OpenSSL` que es donde se encuentra `openssl.exe` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto defino el path completo de [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) al llamar mi comando:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Jorgesys\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Data\OpenSSL\openssl
base64
```

También puedes registrar el path donde se encuentra `openssl.exe` en las [variables de entorno](https://medium.com/@01luisrene/como-agregar-variables-de-entorno-s-o-windows-10-e7f38851f11f)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y simplemente definir el ejecutable al ejecutar el comando:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Jorgesys\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
    base64
```

---

Recuerda definir también la ruta correcta donde se encuentra tu keystore de debug, que es el archivo `debug.keystore` , en windows regularmente se encuentra en esta ruta:

```
C:\Users\<NOMBRE USUARIO>\.android\debug.keystore
```