# Ver la Release.keystore o debug.keystore para Facebook SDK

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

Creé una aplicación React Native hace mucho tiempo. Firmé la aplicación para subirla a Play Store. Sin embargo, ahora necesito integrar el SDK de Facebook y Facebook me pregunta sobre la clave hash. No quiero generar uno nuevo, me gustaría ver la cadena de 28 caracteres, es decir, la clave traducida, no codificada. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Soy un usuario de Mac.

Gracias,
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave hash que comentas, se puede obtener como indica esta respuesta,

[keytool en windows no funciona para obtener hash para Facebook](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151583/keytool-en-windows-no-funciona-para-obtener-hash-para-facebook/151610#151610)

en el caso de una MAC la ventaja es que no tienes que instalar OpenSSL, pero el procedimiento es similar

Abrir `Terminal` y navegar hacia el directorio donde se encuentra el  keystore. Si usas tu Keystore de debug, se ubicará dentro de "/Users//.android/"
Dentro del directorio ".android", se ejecuta el comando:

```
  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Cuando le solicite una contraseña, en el caso del Keystore de debug escribes `android` y presionas `Enter` y obtendrás una salida similar a :

```
478uEnKQV+fMQT8Dy4AKvHkYibo=
```

este valor que finaliza con "=" es tu Key Hash para Facebook.

Te sugiero revisar :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/?locale=es_ES#release-key-hash

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, pensaba que ese comando iba a regenerar cualquiera de las claves, pero visto lo visto parece que no. Simplemente las muestra. Con eso ya he podido completar la configuración.